# what preposition follows than in the given sentence and similar constructions?

Tags: prepositions

> What better way to spend a rainy afternoon than **by** reading a book?
>   What better way to spend a rainy afternoon than reading a book?
>   What better way to spend a rainy afternoon than **to** read a book?

In constructions like this, what preposition do we use after **than**, if any?
Are all the sentences grammatical?

Comment: Note that *to* is not a preposition here, but a marker for the infinitive *to read*.

Answer (score 1):

Each of your three examples is fine. To me, the second one *What better way to spend a rainy afternoon than reading a book?* sounds the most natural.